# Hide custom annoation view on clicking anywherwher in mapview

Tags: ios, swift

How to hide custom annoation view on clicking anywherwher in mapview

I have used touchsBegan method, But it won't work properly when click around pin area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to to use touchesBegan method, Mapview already have diddeselect method to hide annotation view.Try this,

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if view.isKind(of: AnnotationView.self)
    {
        for subview in view.subviews
        {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```